# How to sort a list of n-tuples by a given column, or by the norm?

Tags: syntax, sorting

I would like to sort a list of lists by the third column (third element in  each row), or by the norm of each row, but Mathematica 13.1 ignores my syntax, i.e. returns the same unordered answer

```
li = {{0.00004191985910722503`, 79.92097210722936`, 
   0.060766185734004545`, 0, 
   29.99999999999998`}, {0.00014994759383077448`, \
-15.452103929848745`, 25.987422519385845`, 0, 
   29.99999999999998`}, {-0.00009026030041129928`, 
   10.075376004878375`, -31.662472098711813`, 0, 
   29.99999999999997`}, {0.00036503895052235514`, 0, 
   8.936153508787257`, 0, 29.99999999999997`}, {0.04959888770525874`, 
   47.82577434636914`, 0.09836077272096849`, 0.9512986439409677`, 
   0.03150272258694897`}, {0.22130652895261646`, \
-3.5069216921741706`, -3.937987079111237`, 4.248085355890237`, 
   0.007060342988500552`}, {0.18987400290980555`, 0, 
   0.6671392580124326`, 3.6445808558682673`, 
   0.00822914130452194`}}; li // MatrixForm
Sort[li, #[[3]] &] // MatrixForm
Sort[li, Norm[#] &] // MatrixForm
```

What should be the correct syntax?

Comment: Please look up [`SortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SortBy.html). `SortBy[li, #[[3]] &]` and `SortBy[li, Norm]` would work.